# Using Firebase with React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm creating a React Native application and I want to use Firebase.
I tried to find few tutorials but none was clear enough for me, can you guys link me with a good tutorial to get started with Firebase?
Another question, In the Firebase console, should I choose use Firebase for Web App?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebase Console you need to use the Web App option as the others require the usage of native code.

I would recommend you to take a look at Firestack: https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack

It might be overwhelming at first sight, but it's in my opinion the most solid Library to work with Firebase with ease.